# C# wpf redrawing canvas depeding on Timer event

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm trying to redraw a canvas on a Timer event. When the event is fired, the application crashes with an exception.

[Picture of code of main procedure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ol4Le.png)

[Picture of code handling the timer event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaHY6.png)

Comment: Pasted code is better than web links.

Comment: Why do you comment out the code that uses the `Dispatcher` object?

Comment: You're accessing an UI element from a non UI Thread you need to use dispatcher to run the instruction on UI tread.

Answer (score 2):

Intead of the Timer class use the DispatcherTimer, It executes the tick on the original thread so it can access the UI

Answer (score 0):

Please try to use the DispatcherTimer instead of the normal timer or you have to invoke to main thread for the hole event handler (OnTimedEvent) 
You may use this [Link](http://www.wpf-tutorial.com/misc/dispatchertimer/)